# Android ListView with custom ArrayAdapter error when using setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've attached an xml file to modify the style of my objects shown in a list view creating a custom ArrayAdapter class. Now I want to set a listener that tells me which item has been selected by the user. Not only it gives error messages but also it doesn't execute any code within the method. I tried going back to a simple listView without a custom adapter (using one of the default ones) and it works. I already looked up here and googled the error message and it seems a problem related to SELinux permissions but I haven't changed any of those also because I have no idea on how to do it.

This is the error message:

> W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:5784638): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=21556 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c164,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

This is the adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Schedule> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Schedule> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    Schedule item = getItem(position);

    TextView scheduleName = customView.findViewById(R.id.customRow_scheduleName);
    TextView scheduleStart = customView.findViewById(R.id.customRow_startDate);
    TextView scheduleEnd = customView.findViewById(R.id.customRow_endDate);

    scheduleName.setText(item.getName());
    scheduleStart.setText(item.getStartDate());
    scheduleEnd.setText(item.getEndDate());

    return customView;
}}
```

This is the main class which contains the listView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CreateNewScheduleFragment.OnInputListener {

private ArrayList<Schedule> scheduleCollection;

private ListAdapter customAdapter;

ListView scheduleListView;
Button newScheduleBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    newScheduleBtn = findViewById(R.id.addNewSchedule);

    scheduleCollection = new ArrayList<>();

    //String[] array = {"pippo", "pluto"};

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, scheduleCollection);
    scheduleListView = findViewById(R.id.scheduleListView);
    scheduleListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);//new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));

    // #################### DEBUG
    scheduleCollection.add(new Schedule("Scheda 1", "14-3", "21-04", "ciao"));
    scheduleCollection.add(new Schedule("Scheda 2", "22-05", "5-06", "ciao"));
    ((ArrayAdapter<Schedule>)customAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    // #################### DEBUG

    scheduleListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("info", "I'm item in position " + String.valueOf(position));
        }
    });}
```

This is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fragment_rounded_corners"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customRow_scheduleName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Scheda 1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customRow_startDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/customRow_endDate"
        android:text="14-03"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customRow_endDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="21-05"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/customRow_startDate"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/customRow_startDate"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="period:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customRow_cancelBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the custom object class:

```
package com.example.fabri.gymine;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Schedule {

    private ArrayList<Workout> workouts;
    private String name;
    private String startDate, endDate, filePath;

    public Schedule(String name, String startDate, String endDate, String filePath) {
        this.name = name;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        workouts = new ArrayList<>();

        //loadScheduleFromFile();
    }

    public void removeWorkout(Workout w){
        workouts.remove(w);
    }

    public int workoutCount(){
        return workouts.size();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    private String myReadLine(BufferedReader br) throws IOException{
        String tmp = br.readLine();
        Log.i("Letto", tmp);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your posted code. It works, so problem may be from your layout or custom object class. You can also try clean and rebuild your project. Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried to clean and rebuild the project but it still doesn't work. I edited the question with the code of both custom object class and layout since I also came to the conclusion that could be caused by one of those two but I can't find the problem

Comment: Your problem is weird. I tried all your posted code and it works for me. I tested with **CreateNewScheduleFragment.OnInputListener** as an empty method, **Workout** as an empty class, the two background images with simple PNG images. My testing device is running Android 7.1  Hope these info helpful!

Comment: I tried many times and nothing seems to work so I decided to dump the list view and go for recyclerView instead. It works flawlessly. Should I remove the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Also use

```
   scheduleListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

after

```
scheduleCollection.add(new Schedule("Scheda 1", "14-3", "21-04", "ciao"));
scheduleCollection.add(new Schedule("Scheda 2", "22-05", "5-06", "ciao"));
```

Comment: I added the check which is definitely a good idea but it doesn't solve the problem. Also setting the adapter before or after those two lines doesn't make much difference also because I'm populating the list just to have something ready to work with